# Laravel passport extend access token's expiration time

Tags: laravel, jwt, laravel-passport

I used to use a pure `jwt` library in my PHP projects. For extending the user's token, I use the **refresh token**. There is no such concept in Laravel's **passport**. There is just an access token that has an expiration time.

Imagine I set the time to 1 hour. After one hour, the user gets logged out **while working on the website**. What is the best practice in **Laravel**?

Please don't mention about long time expiration which is not the solution.

Comment: so you want a solution using passport?

Comment: @lagbox Yes, probably.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel Passport does have refresh tokens: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#refreshing-tokens

Refresh tokens can also expire but are rather long-lived. Refresh tokens, if compromised, are useless because the attacker requires the client id and secret in addition to the refresh token in order to gain an access token.

You can customize token lifetimes as described here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#token-lifetimes

Common use cases include getting new access tokens after old ones have expired, or getting access to a new resource for the first time.

Comment: Thanks. But the link you mentioned is for `oauth` protocol. I just want to authorize my user in a simple way.

Comment: Assuming you are developing an API for a first-party app or a SPA, what you are looking for is `password-grant` flow. It is very similar to JWT. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#creating-a-password-grant-client

Comment: As mentioned in docs: `The OAuth2 password grant allows your other first-party clients, such as a mobile application, to obtain an access token using an e-mail address / username and password. This allows you to issue access tokens securely to your first-party clients without requiring your users to go through the entire OAuth2 authorization code redirect flow.`

Comment: I happen to have a couple of boilerplate projects that you can use to understand how that works. 
Nuxt.js usage: https://github.com/pktharindu/nuxt-laravel-passport-example 
Passport boilerplate: https://github.com/pktharindu/laravel-api-boilerplate-passport

Comment: Your `login` route uses `'Laravel\\Passport\\Http\\Controllers\\AccessTokenController@issueToken'`. Does it return both access token and refresh token?

Comment: I mean this file: https://github.com/pktharindu/laravel-api-boilerplate-passport/blob/master/routes/api.php

Comment: Yeah, it does. Depending on the parameters you pass.